# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when access to class property

Tags: swift

I have a very simple code, but when I call `testFunc()` it crashes on line `value = NSObject()` with error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`. Could anyone explain, why does it happens?

```
class A {
    var object: Any?
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(nil)
    }
    
    private init(_ object: Any?) {
        self.object = object
    }
}

class B: A {
    var value: Any?
    
    func test() {
        value = NSObject()
    }
}

func testFunc() {
    let b = B()
    b.test()
}
```

Comment: The error code is particularly curious, it’s a floating point error 

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code in a Mac command line tool, it works just fine. If I run it as an iOS playground, it crashes.

It looks like a bug in playgrounds to me. (It wouldn't be the first time. I find playgrounds pretty unstable, and tend to test out non-UI coding ideas with command line tools rather than playgrounds because I find playgrounds to be flaky and unreliable.)

I tried adding print statements at various points, and the first time I added a print statement it didn't crash. Then several edit/run cycles later, it didn't crash again. I don't see anything wrong with your code (other than the fact that it doesn't really do anything, and there's no real point in creating an empty NSObject.)

Comment: It crashes both on playground and iPhone, but not every time

Comment: This code is useless, but this is just an example to demonstrate the problem.